# How to link nested viewcontrollers using the child viewcontroller pattern

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Compiling and running using iOS 7 - getting warning message: "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged" while presenting modal view controller. I have learned that viewcontrollers with linked using the child viewcontroller pattern will not produce warning. Can someone suggest way to link nested viewcontrollers using the child viewcontroller pattern to avoid warning message.

```
(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        self.loginRootviewController =   [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController-iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
       self.loginRootviewController =   [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    }

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.loginRootviewController];


    DDMenuController *rootController = [[DDMenuController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController];
    _menuController = rootController;



    AppMainMenuViewController *leftController = [[AppMainMenuViewController alloc] init];
    rootController.leftViewController = leftController;
    self.loginRootviewController.delegateLogin = leftController;

    self.window.rootViewController = rootController;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using DDMenuViewController use SWRevealViewController. It is updated for iOS 7 and has more functionality than DD